# User provider missing in symfony2

Tags: symfony

I just implemented my own authentication provider performing facebook authentication. It works for exactly one request and then it goes:

```
There is no user provider for user "Nourdine\BasicBundle\Security\User\FacebookUser"
```

The thing is:

1 - a FacebookProvider is there and kicking.
2 - I registered it as a service:

```
  <service id="facebook_user_provider" class="Nourdine\BasicBundle\Security\User\FacebookUserProvider" />
```

3 - and made it available in security.xml

First question: Why does he now "see" it?
Second question: is it mandatory that one creates a related user provider every time he implements an authentication provider?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you have something wrong with your user provider refreshUser method. This method is used when you use session persistence (token is serialized and stored in session) so user can be fetched from database (or other place) next requests.

1. It see provider cause you register it as service and use service id in security.yml
2. UserProvider is responsible for fetch user from db or other layer (webservice or something) and AuthenticationProvider authenticate user (do authentication logic) and it can use provider but it is not necessary most the time we use `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface` not concrete implementation. So not mandatory